# dplyr: Adding a new row at the end of each group, calculated on variables from the previous row

Tags: r, dplyr, event-log

## Key problem

I am able to fill the new row with the values of the previous row. I can assign constants to vars in the new row. But, I cannot
calculate values based on previous rows and assign them in the new row.

## Background

I have real data from a PLC, that I prepare for conversion to an eventlog for use with `bupaR`.
The data below are limited and simplified but contain information concerning resource, timestamp, state-type, and event_ID.

## Already achieved

- I added Error_ID, Error_startTS, Error_EndTS, and **part of the Life-cycle**, as was documented in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370043/a-loop-approach-to-event-log-preparation-for-bupar-can-this-be-vectorized)
- An **Error** is defined as any series of events that starts with the state_type=="error", until an event is encountered that 
  is anything but "Error", "Comlink Down", "Not Active".
- an **error number** was assigned to all rows of the same "error-trace" ("Error_ID")
- the **start time** of the error (timestamp of 1st error row) was assigned ("Error_startTS")
- the **end time** of the error,, the timestamp of the **1st row after the error**, in other words 
  the timestamp of the event that ends the error was assigned ("Error_endTS")
- a "Life_cycle_ID" was assigned to the rows of the error, either "Start" or "Ongoing".

## Goal:

Now, I want to insert a new row

- with Life_cycle_id == "Complete"
- after the last row of "ongoing" of each "error-trace"

**Details**

- Solvable with `fill()`: copy from last row

  - "Resource"
  - "Error_ID",
  - "Error_startTS",
  - "Error_endTS"
- Solvable with `add.row()`: assign a constant

  - "Lifecycle_ID" should be "Complete"
  - "State_type" should be "Error"
- **Problematic for me:** assign values base on values of the previous rows

  - The time-stamp "Datetime_local" should get the value of "Error_endTS" in the group
  - the "event_ID" should be increased by 1

### The data

```
my_df <- structure(
  list(Resource = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                            .Label = c("L54", "L60", "L66", "L68", "L70", "L76", 
                                       "L78", "L95", "L96", "L97", "L98", "L99"), 
                            class = "factor"), 
       Datetime_local = structure(c(1535952594, 1535952618, 1535952643, 1535952651, 
                                    1535952787, 1535952835, 1535952840, 1535952846, 
                                    1535952890, 1535952949, 1535952952, 1535952958, 
                                    1535953066), 
                                  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
       State_type = structure(c(6L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 12L), 
                              .Label = c("Comlink Down", "Comlink Up", "Counter", "Error", 
                                         "Message", "No part in", "No part out", "Not active", 
                                         "Part changing", "Part in", "Part out", "Producing", 
                                         "Waiting"), 
                              class = "factor"), 
       event_ID = c("e00000000000072160", "e00000000000072270", "e00000000000072400", 
                    "e00000000000072430", "e00000000000072810", "e00000000000073110", 
                    "e00000000000073150", "e00000000000073170", "e00000000000073300", 
                    "e00000000000073520", "e00000000000073540", "e00000000000073570", 
                    "e00000000000074040"), 
       Error_ID = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0), 
       Error_startTS = structure(c(NA, 1535952618, 1535952618, 1535952618, 1535952618, 
                                   1535952618, NA, 1535952846, 1535952846, 1535952846, 
                                   NA, 1535952958, NA), 
                                 class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
       Error_endTS = structure(c(NA, 1535952840, 1535952840, 1535952840, 1535952840, 
                                 1535952840, NA, 1535952952, 1535952952, 1535952952, 
                                 NA, 1535953066, NA), 
                               class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
       Lifecycle_ID = c(NA, "Start", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", NA, 
                        "Start", "Ongoing", "Ongoing", NA, "Start", NA)), 
  .Names = c("Resource", "Datetime_local", "State_type", "event_ID", "Error_ID", 
            "Error_startTS", "Error_endTS", "Lifecycle_ID"), 
  row.names = 160:172, class = "data.frame")
```

## ... looking like this

```
# Resource      Datetime_local State_type           event_ID Error_ID       Error_startTS         Error_endTS Lifecycle_ID
160      L60 2018-09-03 07:29:54 No part in e00000000000072160        0                <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
161      L60 2018-09-03 07:30:18      Error e00000000000072270        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00        Start
162      L60 2018-09-03 07:30:43 Not active e00000000000072400        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00      Ongoing
163      L60 2018-09-03 07:30:51      Error e00000000000072430        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00      Ongoing
164      L60 2018-09-03 07:33:07 Not active e00000000000072810        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00      Ongoing
165      L60 2018-09-03 07:33:55      Error e00000000000073110        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00      Ongoing
166      L60 2018-09-03 07:34:00  Producing e00000000000073150        0                <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
167      L60 2018-09-03 07:34:06      Error e00000000000073170        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52        Start
168      L60 2018-09-03 07:34:50 Not active e00000000000073300        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52      Ongoing
169      L60 2018-09-03 07:35:49      Error e00000000000073520        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52      Ongoing
170      L60 2018-09-03 07:35:52  Producing e00000000000073540        0                <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
171      L60 2018-09-03 07:35:58      Error e00000000000073570        3 2018-09-03 07:35:58 2018-09-03 07:37:46        Start
172      L60 2018-09-03 07:37:46  Producing e00000000000074040        0                <NA>                <NA>         <NA>
```

## The UDF

```
ErrorNumberAddLastRow <- function(df){
  df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(Error_ID) %>%
    do(add_row(.,
               Lifecycle_ID = "Complete", State_type = "Error")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    fill("Resource", "event_ID","Error_ID", "Error_startTS", "Error_endTS") %>%
    # mutate(event_ID = event_ID+1) %>%          # error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
    # mutate(Datetime_local = Error_endTS) %>%   # assigns the same TS to the whole group
    arrange(event_ID) %>% 
    filter( !(Error_ID==0 & Lifecycle_ID=="Complete") | is.na(Lifecycle_ID))
}
```

## Call to the udf

```
ErrorNumberAddLastRow(my_df)
```

## Gives this result

```
# A tibble: 16 x 8
   Resource Datetime_local      State_type event_ID           Error_ID Error_startTS       Error_endTS         Lifecycle_ID
   <chr>    <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>       
 1 L60      2018-09-03 07:29:54 No part in e00000000000072160        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
 2 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:18 Error      e00000000000072270        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Start       
 3 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:43 Not active e00000000000072400        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
 4 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:51 Error      e00000000000072430        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
 5 L60      2018-09-03 07:33:07 Not active e00000000000072810        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
 6 L60      2018-09-03 07:33:55 Error      e00000000000073110        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
 7 L60      NA                  Error      e00000000000073110        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Complete    
 8 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:00 Producing  e00000000000073150        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
 9 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:06 Error      e00000000000073170        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Start       
10 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:50 Not active e00000000000073300        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Ongoing     
11 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:49 Error      e00000000000073520        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Ongoing     
12 L60      NA                  Error      e00000000000073520        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Complete    
13 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:52 Producing  e00000000000073540        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
14 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:58 Error      e00000000000073570        3 2018-09-03 07:35:58 2018-09-03 07:37:46 Start       
15 L60      NA                  Error      e00000000000073570        3 2018-09-03 07:35:58 2018-09-03 07:37:46 Complete    
16 L60      2018-09-03 07:37:46 Producing  e00000000000074040        0 NA                  NA                  NA
```

## Desired result

```
# # A tibble: 16 x 8
# Resource Datetime_local      State_type event_ID           Error_ID Error_startTS       Error_endTS         Lifecycle_ID
# <chr>    <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>       
#  1 L60      2018-09-03 07:29:54 No part in e00000000000072160        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
#  2 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:18 Error      e00000000000072270        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Start       
#  3 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:43 Not active e00000000000072400        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
#  4 L60      2018-09-03 07:30:51 Error      e00000000000072430        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
#  5 L60      2018-09-03 07:33:07 Not active e00000000000072810        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
#  6 L60      2018-09-03 07:33:55 Error      e00000000000073110        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Ongoing     
#  7 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:00 Error      e00000000000073111        1 2018-09-03 07:30:18 2018-09-03 07:34:00 Complete    
#  8 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:00 Producing  e00000000000073150        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
#  9 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:06 Error      e00000000000073170        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Start       
# 10 L60      2018-09-03 07:34:50 Not active e00000000000073300        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Ongoing     
# 11 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:49 Error      e00000000000073520        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Ongoing     
# 12 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:52 Error      e00000000000073521        2 2018-09-03 07:34:06 2018-09-03 07:35:52 Complete    
# 13 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:52 Producing  e00000000000073540        0 NA                  NA                  NA          
# 14 L60      2018-09-03 07:35:58 Error      e00000000000073570        3 2018-09-03 07:35:58 2018-09-03 07:37:46 Start       
# 15 L60      2018-09-03 07:37:46 Error      e00000000000073571        3 2018-09-03 07:35:58 2018-09-03 07:37:46 Complete    
# 16 L60      2018-09-03 07:37:46 Producing  e00000000000074040        0 NA                  NA                  NA
```

**In detail**

On row 7, 12, and 15

- increase event_ID with 1
- add the "Error_endTS" of the group to the Datetime_local time stamp

## When you uncomment the mutate statements in the function

1. `mutate(event_ID = event_ID+1) %>%`

... an error is raised

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric
>   argument to binary operator.

2. `mutate(Datetime_local = Error_endTS) %>%`

... this assigns the same TS to the whole group

**Thank you for any help you can give me.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gsubfn)

my_df %>%
  split(.$Error_ID) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, 
                    Lifecycle_ID = "Complete", 
                    State_type = "Error", 
                    # Take the last event_ID in each group, find the last digit 
                    # in the string, convert it to numeric and add +1
                    event_ID = gsubfn("\\d{1}$", ~ as.numeric(x) + 1, last(.$event_ID)),
                    # Assign Datetime_local to the last Error_endTS in each group
                    Datetime_local = last(.$Error_endTS))) %>%
  fill("Resource", "Error_ID", "Error_startTS", "Error_endTS")
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. So, the trick is in using `last(.$x)`. Thank your very much!

Comment: For completeness sake, to get the exact result in the question, you only have to add at the end  the last 2 rows of the UDF in the question: `arrange(event_ID) %>%  filter( !(Error_ID==0 & Lifecycle_ID=="Complete") | is.na(Lifecycle_ID))`